# Display multiple rows as one in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need some advice on

I created a web app where a user can assign a form to multiple recipients simultaneously so that one assignment inserts multiple rows (one row per recipient) into the `form_assignments` table like so:

```
foreach ($recipients as $row) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO form_assignments 
       (sender_id, recipient_id, form_id, due_date, priority_id, comment, completed) 
       VALUES 
       ('{$sender_id}', " . $row['id'] . ", '{$assigned_form_id}', '2014-04-30 00:00:00', '{$priority_id}', '{$comment}', '{$completed}')";
```

In the example above, `$recipients` is an array with user ids referenced by `$row['id']`.

So, one assignment can generate 100 of these rows (for 100 recipients), for example, and each recipient can edit his individual row as "completed". This is good so far.

The problem is, if I want to generate a list of assignments for the user that assigned them I want him to see only one row for a multiple-user assignment (not one row for each recipient he sent the assignment to).

I'd love to be able to show the user a table like:

*You assigned: form 1 To: 50 users Due on: April 25, 2014 Users Completed: 10 View List of Users*

And each assignee would see a table like:

*User 1 assigned you the following form: form 1 Due on: April 25, 2014, Click to Mark as Completed*

I'm not sure how to go about this. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You should read about `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` in the MySQL Documentation or in some Tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i do understand you correctly, you want to present to the person that assigns, a list of assignments, grouped by assignment and date.
For each Assignment/Date Result, you alos want to present how many Users already completed the Assignment right.

So you want to Select from assignments and [Group](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html) your Result by `sender_id`, `form_id` and `due_date` first:

```
SELECT sender_id, form_id, due_date
FROM assignments as groupedAssignments
GROUP BY 
  groupedAssignments.sender_id, 
  groupedAssignments.form_id, 
  groupedAssignments.due_date
```

Now you also want to `JOIN` the assignments to get th count for how many students already finished this assignment. 
That's why i added the alias 'groupedAssignments'.
So add a `JOIN` After your `FROM`

```
JOIN assignments as finishedAssignments ON (
  groupedAssignments.sender_id = finishedAssignments.sender_id
  AND groupedAssignments.form_id = finishedAssignments.form_id
  AND groupedAssignments.due_date = finishedAssignments.due_date
  AND finishedAssignments.completed = TRUE )
```

Now you can add a Count on the finished assignments giving you the full Query:

```
SELECT 
  groupedAssignments.sender_id, 
  groupedAssignments.form_id, 
  groupedAssignments.due_date, 
  COUNT(finishedAssignments.completed) as finishedStudents
FROM assignments as groupedAssignments
JOIN assignments as finishedAssignments ON (
  groupedAssignments.sender_id = finishedAssignments.sender_id 
  AND groupedAssignments.form_id = finishedAssignments.form_id
  AND groupedAssignments.due_date = finishedAssignments.due_date
  AND finishedAssignments.completed = TRUE )
GROUP BY 
  finishedAssignments.sender_id, 
  finishedAssignments.form_id, 
  finishedAssignments.due_date
```

Obviously i didn't test this and it might not work for you, but it should lead you in the right direction.
Read up on [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html).

Comment: Yes, this sounds like what I'm after. I tried your query but I'm getting syntax errors. I'm trying a few corrections to see if I can get it.

Comment: @Mike I made an edit fixing the Syntax Errors i saw (had `,` between statements). Try it now but make sure to adjust my *pseudo-code* check for your `completed` field because you might store something else than a boolean value right? It wouldn't be SQL-2003 conform either i think.

Comment: Thanks, Andresch. I read up on this and it has been helpful and a bit confusing too. I'll try your solution again with the edits and let you know. Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: @Mike Consider accepting my answer so this question doesn't get any more unneeded attention.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide when rows count as being part of the same assignment (this may mean adding this info to the table). If, for example, you decide that this can be done by matching the sender_id, form_id and due_date then you can group by these fields:

```
SELECT sender_id,form_id,due_date,COUNT(recipient_id)
FROM assignments
GROUP BY sender_id,,form_id,due_date
```

That will give a list of assignments done by the user as well as the count of recipients. Of course this may need tweaked or changed depending on how you decide to match assignments.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I will try your suggestion as well.